# AFNetworking vs BaaS?

Tags: ios, json, cocoa-touch, afnetworking, mbaas

I'm planning to build a simple social app that can allow users to send pictures and text messages. By doing some research I found some people use Backend as a Service(BaaS) to manage database on the server while some people use AFNetworking.

I have two questions that might seem stupid to you:

1. My iOS programming book used NSURL + NSURLRequest + NSURLSessionTask + NSURLSession to get JSON data from network, why do a lot of people use this third party API AFNetworking?
2. What's the benefit of using AFNetworking(vs Baas)? Do I have to write my own server code if I use AFNetworking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are technologies that operate at different layers. You can assemble an architecture using a combination of these.

AFNetworking is a good drop-in replacement for NSURL + NSURLRequest + NSURLSessionTask + NSURLSession. It's a client-side networking framework. It's a good choice if you write your own web server.

Most BaaS platforms have web APIs. AFN would work well with those. So would NSURL*.

Some BaaS platforms like Firebase offer an iOS SDK. In that case you could use the SDK *instead* of AFN or NSURL*.

Comment: Thanks @noa, but what does good drop-in replacement mean? The advantage of AFNetworking is the convenience(use less code) or the functionality(Does it really provides more)?

Comment: @wz366 You need to go read AFNetworking's documentation. It's just a wrapper around NSURLRequest and friends. AFNetworking provides no additional features, but does (in some case drastically) reduce the code necessary to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

`AFNetworking` is just a delightful library that wraps `NSURLSession` and its ilk.  You can use `AFNetworking` in almost any situation that you can use Apple's APIs.

I like `AFNetworking` because it tends to simplify making networking calls to a few lines of code.

Comment: Thanks, is JSON the only type of data AFNetworking can deal with? Can AFNetworking work with database on the sever?

Comment: No. You can use for JSON, XML, property list and images.

Comment: @wz366  AFNetworking can be used to download any file type.  If you want the API to automatically deserialize the data you're expecting, say a PLIST, you will need to set the appropriate `AFURLResponseSerialization` class to handle specific data.

Comment: @Camus Not correct.  `AFNetworking` can download any file. If it doesn't know how to deserialize the data, then it passes you the raw `NSData` to you handle yourself.  This is no different than `NSURLSession` or `NSURLConnection`.

Comment: Thats what I meant. To deserialize the data to a specific one instead of a 'NSData', it only accepts those ones.